# executing script over terminal using electron js application but it requires node js to be installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, terminal, electron

I am presently engaged in a project that involves running a script through the system terminal using my Electron.js application. However, I have encountered a challenge related to new users who may lack technical proficiency and do not have Node.js installed on their systems. I am seeking guidance on potential solutions to execute the script without necessitating the preinstallation of Node.js on their systems.

Functionality:-

- Click on a button and run script over user's Terminal using command like (node "file which is going to be executed"

Problem faced:-

1. Works good for users already having node js enviroment in their system.
2. For users who doesn't have preinstalled node js environment in that case js script is not get executed over there system terminal or command promt

Solution what i am looking for :-
handle the script execution either they already have or not node js environment script needs to be get executed over their system command propt or terminal

Could you please provide the relevant code for further analysis and assistance?here is my code
ipcMain.on('run-command', (event, command) => {
const resources = process.resourcesPath;

```
// const swapPath = app.isPackaged
//   ? path.join(process.resourcesPath, "app","dist","main")
//   : path.join(__dirname, command);

// Capturing terminal commands
let terminalCommand: string;
if (process.platform === 'win32') {
  terminalCommand = 'cmd';
} else if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
  terminalCommand = 'osascript';
} else {
  terminalCommand = 'gnome-terminal'; // Adjust for Linux
}

const commands =app.isPackaged && process.platform === 'win32' ? `node ./resources/app/dist/main/${command}`  :app.isPackaged?`npm run ${command}` :`npm run ${command}`;
const currentDirectory = process.cwd();
const macScript = `
```

tell application "Terminal"
do script "cd ${app.isPackaged ? resources :currentDirectory} && ${commands}"
end tell
`;

```
const args = process.platform === 'win32' ? ['/K', commands]
            : process.platform === 'darwin' ? ['-e', macScript]
            : ['--', 'bash', '-c', commands]; // Adjust for Linux

const spawnOptions =
  process.platform === 'win32'
    ? { detached: true, stdio: 'ignore', shell: true }
    : { stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] }; // Adjust for non-Windows platforms
const childProcess = spawn(terminalCommand, args, spawnOptions);

childProcess.on('error', (error: any) => {
  console.error('Child process error:', error);
  event.reply('command-result', { error: error.message });
});

childProcess.on('exit', (code: boolean) => {
  console.log('Terminal process exited with code:', code);
  event.reply('command-result', { exitCode: code });
});
```

});

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understood correctly. U want to use 'npm run something' in user terminal, or u want to execute some other command in user terminal. Could u tell me what is the exact command u want to execute in user terminal.

I have 2 functions, that i execute on user pc from electron.

```
function run_script(command, args, callback) {
          var child = child_process.spawn(command, args, {
            encoding: 'utf8',
            shell: true,
          });

          child.on('error', (error) => {
            // dialog.showMessageBox({
            //   title: 'Title',
            //   type: 'warning',
            //   message: 'Error occured.\r\n' + error,
            // });
          });

          child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
          child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
          });

          child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
          child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            mainWindow.webContents.send('mainprocess-response', data);

            console.log(data);
          });

          if (typeof callback === 'function') callback();
        }
        run_script('start ms-paint:c', ['/ForceBootstrapPaint3D']);
```

And the another one:

```
 const powershellCommand = `start ms-windows-store://pdp/?productid=9NBLGGH5FV99`;
        const { shell } = require('electron');
        const { exec } = require('child_process');

        exec(`powershell.exe -Command "${powershellCommand}"`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(`Błąd wykonania komendy: ${error}`);
            return;
          }
        });
```

Comment: I want to run command on users terminal which will be like node "some file"  but it requires users to have node environment pre-install in there system so is there any thing possible we can do so either users have node environment in there system or not they will be able to execute that on there system

Comment: I mean u can't run something on users pc if user does not have it. U can check if user has node.js installed and then run ur command and if not u can prompt message or redirect to node.js install etc.